# Spring Boot failing to launch with no error

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application I have I been working on and it was working fine. Until this morning when for some reason changes that I made to the code were not being applied when I ran spring boot. So I restarted the PC and now it wont even start up properly.

Console Log

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

Jul 29, 2019 12:44:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jul 29, 2019 12:44:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
Jul 29, 2019 12:44:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Jul 29, 2019 12:44:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

I have added

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG
```

To my application.properties file but it doesn't seem to make a difference as the directory

```
AppData\Local\Temp\1\tomcat.769176152716962805.8080
```

is empty and the console log shows no errors. Eclipse hast flagged any errors in the code and I am baffled as to what is going on.

I would like to know if there is a fix that I just haven't found yet or if something is wrong with the project. If any more code or property files are need please let me know, also the SLF4J has always been there.

Update - 
I tried creating a new spring boot project with a simple hello world and had the same issue. For some reason spring boot isn't picking up the application any more and because of this the tomcat just stops. Still don't know how to fix this. I have also found some error messages but I'm not exactly sure what they mean.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.8.0.I20180611-0500
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core
Warning
Tue Jul 30 06:49:47 BST 2019
Error occured while running bean post processors

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:267)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:432)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.metadata.process.JdtConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcess(JdtConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig$3.run(BeansJavaConfig.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig.executePostProcessor(BeansJavaConfig.java:321)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig.access$5(BeansJavaConfig.java:319)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig$2.call(BeansJavaConfig.java:233)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig$2.call(BeansJavaConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



eclipse.buildId=4.8.0.I20180611-0500
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core
Error
Tue Jul 30 06:51:42 BST 2019
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core".

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:267)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:432)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.metadata.process.JdtConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcess(JdtConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig$3.run(BeansJavaConfig.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig.executePostProcessor(BeansJavaConfig.java:321)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig.access$5(BeansJavaConfig.java:319)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig$2.call(BeansJavaConfig.java:233)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansJavaConfig$2.call(BeansJavaConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Maybe a previous run terminated brutally and there are lock files present? Have you checked for any lock files or other left overs in your project dir? If there are any, delete them. If your code is checked in a revision system. Delete your complete workspace and checkout your code.

Comment: I deleted anything that could be preventing it from re compiling properly and loaded the project into a new workspace. This change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Based on the error, I assume you start the Spring Boot application out of eclipse, maybe with the Spring Tool Suite (STS) plugin? Have you tried running the app without eclipse? So either via maven, if you use it, or if you bundle your app as a jar and simply start the jar from command line? Intenion is, if the maven / command line works just fine, than the problem is not within your app, but with the STS plugin.

Comment: Im not exactly sure whats wrong but im pretty sure that it was spring that wasnt picking up the application. Luckily the application wasnt that big so I have re built it on a fresh install of eclipse and it seems to be fine now thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, nice to hear that the issue is gone. I also think that the STS plugin had some kind of hickup.

Comment: The current version of Spring Boot is 2.4.5.  You ought to upgrade.  2.1.6 is old.